# Changing $_Post Search Results To Words Rather Than Category Number

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

On my custom search results page I have a line that displays what category and price. The code I'm using is

```
Displaying results for <?php echo $_POST['category_name']; ?>
```

The output for this code is "Displaying results for 18120".

I'm looking to display the word "Audio" rather than "18120", as well as about 10 other categories.

My current attempt, shown below, is not working properly.

```
<?php $cat = $_POST['category_name']; ?>

<?php if ($cat == 18120) echo 'Audio';
  elseif ($cat == 18121) echo 'Television';
?>
```

Comment: Maybe I had the code in the wrong place? Based off your input I have it working. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else/if`, store the new name, rather than echoing it. Then use that variable in your display:

```
<?php $cat = $_POST['category_name']; ?>

<?php if ($cat == 18120) $cat = 'Audio';
  elseif ($cat == 18121) $cat = 'Television';
?>

Displaying results for <?php echo $cat; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To save aload of `else` and `if` why not use the good old `switch` and `case`?

```
switch ($_POST['Category_name']){
    case 18120:
        $Cat = "Audio";
        break;
    case 18121:
        $Cat = "Television";
        break;
    case 18122:
        $Cat = "Something Else";
        break;
}

echo $Cat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use get_category() wordpress function:

```
<?php 
$catCode = $_POST['category_name']; 
if(is_numeric($catCode)) {
    $cat = get_category($catCode);
    echo $cat->name;
} else {
  echo $catCode;
}
?>
```

Enjoy your code!

Comment: I''m sure you might have mis-matching variables `$CatId !== $Cat`, so if i'm correct. OP might encounter undefined indexes

Comment: Yes @DarylGill, you have right. I correct my code. Thanks